# Email Notification

Tags: email, jsp

How to write the jsp code for auto generate a notification for a user if the user have an email inside the inbox.

Comment: This is a bit vague. What inbox do you mean?

Comment: i doing the function for sending email after that the email send by the user will be shown.So i want it to show a notification that the user have a new message.

Comment: the notification will be shown after the user have login.

Comment: You should try Server-Push for this.

Answer (score 0):

You keep a place on your page which is usually empty (Empty Picture) and if there is a notification's reason you show another picture in this space which indicates this.
Each time the page is reloaded this code will be run.

Should you want his more interactive like the notification you see on Stackoverflow when an answer is posted while you write your own answer, you will have to implement something like a watchdog which keeps asking the inobox state each priode of time and use Javascript functionality, if im not wrong ajax could be usuful here but im not really sure about this.